# Why does this chemfig bond with a hook start in the middle of the atom?

Tags: chemfig

I've been using the `chemfig` package to typeset my chemistry notes, and when trying to make an arene something went wrong:

[image: myattempt]

Naturally, I'd like it to *not* start from the middle of the atom. The chemfig documentation has an example similar to this:

[image: documentation]

That example works fine for me too. Yet for some reason, my very similar attempt seems to start too early. How could I fix this?

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
C?[firstC](-[::-30]R) %right lower carbon
-[:90]C(-[::-60]R) %right upper
=[::60]C(-[::-60]R) %top
-[::60]C(-[::-60]R) %left upper 
=[::60]C(-[::-60]R) %left lower
-[::60]C(?[firstC,2])(-[::-60]R)} %bottom 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second hook is inside of a branch. Just remove the parentheses from the hook, `C?[firstC,2]` instead of `C?([firstC,2])`. Below I also propose a second version of the molecule using `chemfig`'s ring syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\chemfig{
  C?[firstC](-[::-30]R) %right lower carbon
  -[:90]C(-[::-60]R) % right upper
  =[::60]C(-[::-60]R) % top
  -[::60]C(-[::-60]R) % left upper 
  =[::60]C(-[::-60]R) % left lower
  -[::60]C?[firstC,2](-[::-60]R)
} %bottom 

\bigskip or alternatively:

\chemfig{C*6((-R)-C(-R)=C(-R)-C(-R)=C(-R)-C(-R)=)}

\end{document}
```

[image]